# Populating a Column in Excel Without Using Fill Handle

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Evening all:

Is there a way to populate a column with the same value without using fill handle?  Is there a way to also populate a formula the same way in a column?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options depending on what you're trying to achieve, but the fill handle is one of the best ones. Some others are:

- Select the range, type the formula, validate with
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Copy the formula, select the destination, paste it.
- Home Ribbon \ Editing \ Fill

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget about typing the value into each cell in the column.  In Excel 2003 or earlier, you'll be done after about 65,000 cells -- nothing to it.  Excel 2007+ will take a bit longer, as there are over a million cells per column.

Comment: This would increases the file size and the calculation time when there are other option available.

Comment: Typing a value into 65,000 cells?  Sorry that you cannot appreciate sarcasm.  The OP's question is pretty ridiculous... how can I do *something* other than the super-easy way that has been made available to do it.  In any case, your comment is not correct... the end result is what the OP requested, a column filled with the same value, so it does not "increase file size" over what the desired output is.

Comment: @ExactaBox And what about dragging the fill handle to 100k cells?
The question is not stupid, if it can be done using a shortcut key, it will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Yes for a formula if it is a column adjacent to a tale. If you have a data table i.e. an area of data made up of rows and columns, select the area and from the ribbon select Insert > Table. The area is now an Excel Table and does all kinds of neat things. If you add a formula  into the next free column on the first row, Excel will copy it for all rows. It will also continue to repeat it every time you add a new row to you table - no work required.

Excel Table are a really great way to work with manually maintained data, they have loads features like automated totals, and you can create formulas that use the column headings instead of meaningless cell references.

If you want to know more do a search for tables in Excel's help and look at table overview.

If you wanted to do the same for values you would have to enter them as formulas such as =1.

Another option is to create a macro on the Worksheet_Change Event.

Comment: Where does the OP mention a data table?  Or even adjacent columns having any data in them?  All he asked was how to populate a column.  What about your comment about increasing file size and calculation time... don't you think creating a Data Table does this?  Sorry but -1